# Android: ListActivity does not display any Item

Tags: java, android, list, listview

I hope you help me with this problem. My ListActivity Class woudlnt show ant item in the list

this is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Sale2 extends ListActivity {
    private static final int DIALOG_ID = 100;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    DBAdapter db;

    private CursorAdapter dataSource;

    private View entryView;

    private EditText firstNameEditor;

    private EditText lastNameEditor;

    private static final String fields[] = { "_id", "_date", "_soldPrice" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            db = new DBAdapter(this);
            db.open();
            Cursor data = db.getAllSales2();
            System.out.println("after getallsales2");
            dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data,
                    fields, new int[] { R.id._id, R.id.first, R.id.last });
            System.out.println("after simplecursoradapter"
                    + dataSource.toString());

            setListAdapter(dataSource);
            System.out.println("setListAdapter");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Notes:

Im sure that the cursor has some data on it. But It wouldnt display them

Help is appreciated

Comment: Put a `Log` entry after you make the query(after the line `Cursor data = db.getAllSales2();
`) and see what number does `data.getCount()` returns.

Comment: are you sure you are getting correct column names out from sqlite database?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a call to setContentView(View), which contains a listview which should be populated with data from Cursor

Comment: Wrong, he is extending a `ListActivity` which has a `ListView` as its content view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Sale2 extends ListActivity {
    private static final int DIALOG_ID = 100;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    DBAdapter db;

    private ListAdapter dataSource;

    private View entryView;

    private EditText firstNameEditor;

    private EditText lastNameEditor;

    private static final String fields[] = { "_id", "_date", "_soldPrice" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            db = new DBAdapter(this);
            db.open();
            Cursor data = db.getAllSales2();
            System.out.println("after getallsales2");
            startManagingCursor(data);
            dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data,
                    fields, new int[] { R.id._id, R.id.first, R.id.last });
            System.out.println("after simplecursoradapter"
                    + dataSource.toString());

            setListAdapter(dataSource);
            System.out.println("setListAdapter");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I have changed the dataSource to `ListAdapter` and also added the `startManagingCursor`.

Also see the example over here

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to use the reference to the ListView, but as you have extended the ListActivity instead of Activity, you must get the **reference to the ListActivity's List as follow:**

`ListView lv =` **getListView();**

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set the adapter on the list object loaded from xml. Something like:

```
listaNodiView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewLista);
listaNodiView.setListAdapter(dataSource);
```

where `R.id.ListViewLista` is the id of the List resource inside your layout xml declaration (NOT row.xml)

Comment: you are wrong. From the doc: Resource identifier of a layout file that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"